# Is it wrong to require/import a class that is already imported higher up the inheritance chain?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, objection.js

I have an external library ([Objection.js](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/)) that I'm using in my Node.js app. I created a base model class that extends Objection's `Model` class for my entity models:

```
const { Model } = require('objection')

class ModelBase extends Model {
    // implementation not important for this question
}
```

In my model classes that extend my base, there are times, specifically when coding the `relationMappings`, where I have to access properties/enumerations on the `Model` base class. I *could* do this in my extended models like this:

```
const ModelBase = require('./model-base')

class SomeModel extends ModelBase {
    static get relationMappings () {
        const SomeOtherModel = require('./some-other-model')
        return {
            someOtherModel: {
                relation: ModelBase.BelongsToOneRelation,
                modelClass: SomeOtherModel,
                // etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `relation: ModelBase.BelongsToOneRelation` line. This works, but I think it is misleading, as `BelongsToOneRelation` is NOT a member of `ModelBase`. What seems more explicit and correct to me is to import/require the `Model` from Objection so I can access the `BelongsToOneRelation` from there, like:

```
const { Model } = require('objection')
// other code just like above until the relationMappings...
                relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation
```

I prefer this approach. Will it cause problems, like require loops or the JavaScript version of a circular dependency, if I import/require a class that is already in scope in the inheritance chain?

Comment: No, it won’t cause problems. “Already in scope in the inheritance chain” isn’t a thing, scopes and inheritance are completely separate.

Comment: OK, thanks, should I delete my question then since you answered it?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you think someone else will have the same question, you can leave it up, otherwise it’s safe to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it cause problems, like require loops or the JavaScript version of a circular dependency, if I import/require a class that is already in scope in the inheritance chain?

No. A module will be executed when required for the first time, then if the execution finished the `exports` object gets cached, and further `require()`s will return the same object.

If you have a circular dependency, one of the `require()`s will return the exports object before the module executed, so the exports object will be empty by then, but will be filled up with properties later on.

Therefore even circular dependencies might work correctly, but if they fail it will cause you headaches so always try to not cause that.

Answer (score 2):

> I think it is misleading, as `.BelongsToOneRelation` is NOT a member of `ModelBase`

Actually it is: it is an *inherited* member.

> I prefer to explicitly import the superclass and access the member there. Will it cause problems, like require loops or the JavaScript version of a circular dependency?

No, it won't. The inheritance hierarchy and scope have nothing to do with your module dependencies.